# An easy way to detect if a process crashed (or stopped)?

Tags: c++, c, linux

I need to detect if a process stopped (doesn't matter if crashed, exited normally, or anything else).

My setup is like this :
- task A - does some processing (and occasionally crashes).
- task B - starts the task A, and waits for results

My idea is to open a file in task A right at the beginning, and to use [inotify](http://linux.die.net/man/7/inotify) in task B to detect when task A opened and closed the file. When task A stops (normally or crash), the file will be closed, and task B will detect this.
(when task A crashes, the file will be closed, right?)

My questions are :
- Is the above going to work?
- Is there a simpler or better way to detect task A stopping?

PS If it matters, I am using fedora 9

**EDIT**
The setup above is very simplified. I have 2 of task B, and about 30 of task A. Therefore, I can not use `system` and `fork`

Comment: I don't think that the fact you've got 30 tasks A or so changes anything when using fork().

Answer (score 3):

It is much easier to use daemon monitoring tools like `runit` or `watch`. These are custom-made for this job, e.g. watching a controlled process run and die. If you do code this yourself, use `wait` and friends to wait for a spawned process.

Answer (score 2):

taskB should use `fork()` to make taskA its child process.  Then you can `wait(&status)`
(in C)... `status` will hold the exit code of task A.  You can read `status` to check to see if it exited normally or with some sort of error code.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a tcp socket - i.e. set B up as a server and allow A to connect. B should write a byte to A periodically (whatever delay you want before detecting that A has gone away). When the connection goes away (i.e. the write fails) you know A has gone away.